# Add attribute to checkbox Backgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, backgrid

Hello guys I am using backgrid to render my table which by chance also have some checkboxes. Now I want to add 2 attributes to those checkboxes but I can't figure out how to do it. Can somebody tell me how can I accomplish it. Thanks

**HTML**

```
<div id="dayResult" class="backgrid-container" style="width: 139PX; height: initial; "></div>
```

**JS**

```
var grid1 = new Backgrid.Grid({
  columns: [ {
    name: "name",
    label: "",
    cell: "string"
  },{
    // name is a required parameter, but you don't really want one on a select all column
    name: " ",
    // Backgrid.Extension.SelectRowCell lets you select individual rows
    cell: "select-row",
    // Backgrid.Extension.SelectAllHeaderCell lets you select all the row on a page
    // headerCell: "select-all",

  }],

  collection: new Backbone.Collection([
    {"name": "Monday"},
    {"name": "Tuesday"},
    {"name": "Wednesday"},
    {"name": "Thursday"},
    {"name": "Friday"},
    {"name": "Saturday"},
    {"name": "Sunday"}
  ])
});

$("#dayResult").append(grid1.render().el);
```

**Files that are being included for this**

> CSS

```
<link href="../assets/css/backgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../assets/plugins/backgrid-selectall/css/backgrid-select-all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="../assets/plugins/switchery/switchery.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

> JS

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jashkenas/underscore/1.5.2/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jashkenas/backbone/1.1.0/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/wyuenho/backbone-pageable/master/lib/backbone-pageable.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/wyuenho/backgrid/master/lib/backgrid.js"></script>

    <script src="./assets/plugins/backgrid-selectall/js/backgrid-select-all.js" ></script>


<script src="./assets/plugins/switchery/switchery.js"></script>
```

**CDN URL's**

```
Switchery 
   https://cdn.rawgit.com/abpetkov/switchery/master/switchery.css
   https://cdn.rawgit.com/abpetkov/switchery/master/switchery.js

Backgrid
    https://cdn.rawgit.com/wyuenho/backgrid/master/lib/backgrid.css
    https://cdn.rawgit.com/wyuenho/backgrid-select-all/master/backgrid-select-all.css
    https://cdn.rawgit.com/wyuenho/backgrid/master/lib/backgrid.js
    https://cdn.rawgit.com/wyuenho/backgrid-select-all/master/backgrid-select-all.js
```

Comment: What attributes are you trying to add? Can you not use backgrid event api and then assign attributes after the table has been rendered.

Comment: @JeremyRajan I am trying to add these two attributes `data-render='switchery' data-theme='default'`.

Comment: @JeremyRajan I don't know how to make a fiddle. I can share the code. Will that work

Comment: @JeremyRajan I have added the code

Comment: Great stuff! So, you want to assign those attr to all checkboxes in the table, right?

Comment: @JeremyRajan one thing more these attributes require swtichery files

Comment: @JeremyRajan I can send you all the CDN urls just give me 2 minutes

Comment: @JeremyRajan I have added the CDN urls

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the `render()` method of your checkbox column cell.

I do something similar for adding attributes to my checkbox images. I dont use the "select-row" approach, but I am sure you can extend it like so:

```
   cell: Backgrid.Cell.extend({
    className: '4YearDegree',
    render: function() {
        var degree = this.model.get("Degree");
        var src = '';

        var altText = '';
        if (degree) {                
            src = '../Content/Images/enabled_checkmark.png'; //display enabled checkmark image 
            altText = 'is checked';
            } else {
            src = '../Content/Images/disabled_checkmark.png'; //display disabled checkmark image 
            altText = 'is unchecked';
            }

        this.$el.html($('<img>').attr('src', src).attr('alt', altText));
        return this;
        }
    })
```

The key part of the code above is this line:

```
this.$el.html($('<img>').attr('src', src).attr('alt', altText));
```

I use it to append "altText" to my checkmark images.

Try adding your own custom attributes that way. It could/should work.